# modify model.fit in multi-label classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

**Introduction**

I am doing a multilabel image classification. In my script (find below), I have my initial dataframe with Folder (the class), File (filename), and Tags (labels). With the help of sklearn's MultiLabelBinarizer, the tags are being transformed into corresponding arrays.

With the help of added function, I transformed the Generator so that it yields new arrays in place of tags as `y_true`

**Problem**

The problem is that during the training my val_accuracy is around 0.000 and something. I think I have this because

- `y_true` is an array `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`
- `y_predicted` can be an array something like `[0.9, 0.95, 0.88, 0.1, 0.00, 0.01]`

**Question**

Can you advise me on how to modify model.fit to resolve this issue

```
# Variable assignments
num_classes = 11
img_height = 84
img_width = 112
channels = 3
batch_size = 32
epoch_n = 10
dropout_rate = 0.4

# Make the input layer
new_input = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, channels),
                  name='image_input')

# Download and use EfficientNetB5
tmp = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB5(include_top=True,
                                           weights='imagenet',
                                           input_tensor=new_input,
                                           pooling='max')

# Creating our main model
model = Sequential()
model.add(tmp)  # adding EfficientNetB5

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=256,
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(units=1024,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(units=256,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

model.add(Dense(num_classes,
                activation='sigmoid'))

opt = optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics='categorical_accuracy')

# Import of the data
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=15,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        validation_split=0.3
        )

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_train,
    directory=bulk_train_path,
    x_col='File',
    y_col='Folder',
    class_mode='raw',
    color_mode="grayscale",
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    interpolation='lanczos',
    batch_size=32,
    subset='training')

valid_generator = data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_train,
    directory=bulk_train_path,
    x_col='File',
    y_col='Folder',
    class_mode='raw',
    color_mode="grayscale",
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    interpolation='lanczos',
    batch_size=32,
    subset='validation')

# Fit a MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(df_train['Tags'].values.tolist())

# The helper function
def multilabel_flow_from_dataframe(data_generator, mlb):
    i = 0
    for x, y in data_generator:
        indices = y.astype(np.int).tolist()
        
        my_batch_classes = []
        for j in indices:
            my_batch_classes.append(mydict[j])

        y_multi = mlb.transform(
            my_batch_classes)
        
        yield x, y_multi


multilabel_train_generator = multilabel_flow_from_dataframe(
    train_generator, mlb,
)

multilabel_valid_generator = multilabel_flow_from_dataframe(
    valid_generator, mlb
)


# Model Fitting with checkpoints and EarlyStopping
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(check_path, monitor='val_categorical_accuracy',
                             verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=False, mode='auto',
                             save_freq='epoch')
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=19,
                      verbose=1, mode='auto')
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', factor=0.75,
                              patience=5, min_delta=0.001, min_lr=1e-6)
csv_logger = CSVLogger(log_path)

hist = model.fit(multilabel_train_generator,
                 steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator.labels) // batch_size,
                 epochs=epoch_n,
                 validation_steps=len(valid_generator.labels) // batch_size,
                 validation_data=multilabel_valid_generator,
                 callbacks=[
                     checkpoint, 
                     early, 
                     reduce_lr, 
                     csv_logger])
```